# I've created an Attached Property, now how do I use it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties, attached-properties

I'm trying to determine if Attached Behaviors are something we need in **building controls** for the forms in our application.

Hence, I not only want to know how to **create** Attached Behaviors but want to see real instances in which they are **used** to solve problems. I used [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx#howused) to create a UserControl with an attached property in a way that I think would be useful, namely, a stackpanel in which certain child elements are either **highlighted** or not highlighted.

This example runs fine, but where do I put the logic to **highlight** or not highlight (e.g. change the background color) of the **child** elements?

**XAML:**

```
<Window x:Class="TestAttachedProperties2343.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestAttachedProperties2343"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Grid>
        <local:ExtendedStackPanel>
            <TextBlock local:ExtendedStackPanel.IsHighlighted="True" Text="text1"/>
            <TextBox local:ExtendedStackPanel.IsHighlighted="False" Text="text2"/>
            <TextBox local:ExtendedStackPanel.IsHighlighted="True" Text="text3"/>
        </local:ExtendedStackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Code Behind:**

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System;

namespace TestAttachedProperties2343
{
    public partial class ExtendedStackPanel : StackPanel
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsHighlightedProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "IsHighlighted",
            typeof(Boolean),
            typeof(ExtendedStackPanel),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender));

        public static void SetIsHighlighted(UIElement element, Boolean value)
        {
            element.SetValue(IsHighlightedProperty, value);
        }
        public static Boolean GetIsHighlighted(UIElement element)
        {
            return (Boolean)element.GetValue(IsHighlightedProperty);
        }

        public ExtendedStackPanel()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a real altough very simple example: an attached behavior that shows a message when a user clicks a button. The message can be customized via a dependency property in the behavior itself.

**The behavior code:**

```
public class MyBehavior : Behavior<Button>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MessageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Message",
        typeof(string), typeof(MyBehavior),
        new PropertyMetadata("Default message"));

    public MyBehavior()
        : base()
    { }

    public string Message
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MessageProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MessageProperty, value); }
    }

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Click);
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        base.OnDetaching();
        AssociatedObject.Click -= new RoutedEventHandler(AssociatedObject_Click);
    }

    void AssociatedObject_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(Message);
    }
}
```

**The XAML that uses the behavior:**

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" Content="Click me for custom behavior">
    <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:MyBehavior Message="Hello from custom behavior"/>
    </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

They key here is that you must override the `OnAttached` and `OnDetached` methods. Here you attach/detach handlers to whatever events you want to control in the associated element, and do whatever you want in the handlers. It is a very powerful and flexible way for adding interactivity to visual controls.

**Update**

The base `Behavior<>` class is in the `System.Windows.Interactivity.dll` assembly which is not part of the Silverligh runtime, but is installed with Microsoft Expression Blend 3. It seems anyway that this assembly can be freely redistributed (see here: http://social.expression.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/blend/thread/8523aec4-1a10-4864-8ad4-f95a3627bb4a)

Comment: What do I need to reference to use the "Behavior" class, I find only System.ComponentModel.CategoryAttribute.Behavior (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.categoryattribute.behavior.aspx) in System.dll, which I have referenced by it says type "Behavior" cannot be found.

Comment: You need to reference the System.Windows.Interactivity assembly. It is installed as part of Expression Blend 3.

Comment: This works well in WPF and I technically understand how it works. I am think how we could use this in our forms, perhaps to instead of a message define an ItemType (Customer or Employee) and therefore have different validations, messages, etc. How do you use it in real world applications?